# Decode a field of kafka data from Avro using Flink sql client and Creating a UDF

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, user-defined-functions, avro, flink-sql

I want to decode the “load” field from binary to a readable data using  a UDF created based on a schema of the avro ( supposing I have the schema data.avsc)
Please, Any idea how to create this UDF based on my flink sql code ?

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dataSQL(
  `time` TIMESTAMP(3) METADATA FROM 'timestamp', 
  `metadata` MAP<STRING NOT NULL, VARCHAR NOT NULL> NOT NULL, 
  `load` BYTES NOT NULL
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'topic' = 'top1',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'xxxxxxxx',
  'properties.group.id' = 'flink__0',
  'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
  'format' = 'avro'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no UDF support in the Flink catalog/DDL, but only in the actual query. If you want to apply custom deserialization, you'll need to create your own format implementation.

Comment: Thanks , do you have any  resources that could help me to do that ? or exemple ?

Comment: I would recommend checking out the current `flink-avro` implementation to understand how the serde works and fork that. I'm not aware of any public examples.